# loss ratio is good but model accuracy is always 0

Tags: deep-learning, fast-ai

I am working on accident dataset with fastai and the loss ratio keeps on decreasing with each epoch but accuracy keeps at 0.000000.

below is my google colab notebook.
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1NpNDzgAqS7TKlGcLKH-BKUS4gFL9zNCW?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by selection correct variables in categorical and continuous types.